# Arduino UNO R3 not detected by Arduino Create Agent

Tags: arduino-uno, web

So I just got my Arduino Uno R3 and tried to use it with Arduino Web IDE. I installed (and reinstalled) Arduino Create Agent and was expecting it autodetect my board, but it did not happen. Below is a picture of my board [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IZD6WSam4vAILJY0qimS7KRH5LBvEC2X/view?usp=sharing). One light is solid and the other is flashing. In device manager I see USB serial with exclamation mark. Do I need to installed any drivers? This page says that I do not need to:
[getting started](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUno)
Any thoughts?

P.S. I also openned debug console, but there is nothing useful, it keeps scrolling: Network Port and Serial Port.

P.P.S. I tried two different USB cables, still no luck

P.P.P.S. I installed desktop IDE, selected Arduino Uno and tried to upload, but got back error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sketch uses 444 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

Serial port not selected.



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: `In device manager I see USB serial with exclamation mark` ... what does the exclamation mark mean?

Comment: Install driver for the CH340 USB chip on your Uno

Comment: I never used the Web IDE, but can you find a "Serial port" setting anywhere? The message `Serial port not selected` indicates that it does not know which port to use. Since you could have connected more than one Arduino, you have to tell it which serial port it should use (typically COM3 or COM4)

Comment: @PMF How can I tell it which port to use?

Comment: @Juraj Thank you, but how can I install it on Uno if I cannot connect it to computer?

Comment: @user1700890 If the port is visible in device manager, it is shown there. You should see something like "USB Serial CH340 (COM4)".

Comment: Thank you, All! Indeed, it looks like I need to install CH340 USB driver on my Windows 10. I tried my Arduino with Ubuntu and it worked almost perfectly. Too bad Windows comes without this driver.